# vertical-align bottom is not working

Tags: css, vertical-alignment

I thought that I had done as some of the the examples here on stackoverflow. But it does not work for me! This should be such a simple thing to do. The html structure is set and cannot be changed. CSS is the way I have to go. I have tried Absolute and relative and it did not work with the other surrounding code.

```
<div class="div_lnd_intro">
<div class="lnd_head">
<a class="lndtitle" href="/hantverkshuset/index.php/om-hantverkshuset/nyhetsarkiv/21-arets-foeretagare-2014">Här kan alla medlemmar i vår företagsorganisation nominera till Årets företagare 2014</a>
<span class="lnd_introdate">22 augusti 2013</span>
</div>
<div class="lnd_introtxt"> Nu är det dags att nominera företag till “Årets företagare 2014”. </div>
</div>

.lnd_head {
    border: #C3C solid 1px !important;
    height: 59px !important;
}

.lnd_head a {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
    float: left !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    border: #F66 solid 1px !important;
    max-width: 75% !important;
}

span.lnd_introdate {
    vertical-align: bottom !important;
    height: 100% !important;
    display: table-cell !important;
    float: right !important;
    border: #099 solid 1px !important;
}

.lnd_introtxt {
    clear: both !important;
    float: left !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0 !important;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/TheWizl/5WU2q/2/

Thanks in advance

/Magnus

Comment: If you use display:table-cell it behaves like table cell so you should have table wrapper too..

Comment: Why `!important` for the rules?

Comment: `The html structure is set and cannot be changed.` This always makes me cringe, who wrote the HTML? God?

Comment: I had table-cell set earlier. Dont know why I did not have it in my example. All the !important tags are there because I work with Joomla, Gantry and Joomla add-ons and I have to override Less-code. I got tired of searching for the source of the problem and now I use it by default. Maybe not the best way but searching in Less is a bitch (google translation).

Comment: And therefore the html structure is set...

Comment: Thanks everybody. You saved my day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `display: table;` to your `.lnd_head` declaration block.  Remove the `float` declarations from the `span.lnd_introdate` and and `.lnd_head a` declaration blocks.

Comment: Thanks! Did not think that float was the problem. Now I just have to set width and it is solved.